# How to get the label and values from multiple TextArea material ui with same onchange function for all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textarea

```
data = {"ConnectionString/File Url":"Please enter the file URL of the data from the cloud ",
        "Credentials/SASToken":"Please enter the SAS Token of the data from the cloud"}
```

I have the following data above which helps create the Textarea using a loop but the same onchange function. I want to use the same onchange for all textarea but the problem is i am only able to get the value and not the label as default

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    modal: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: '1px solid #f7f7f7',
        margin: "2rem 0",
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
        padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
    },
}));
export default function ConnectionParams(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const handleClose = () => {
        props.closeModal();
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("on submit");
        console.log("abcd",document.getElementsByName("items"));
    }

    const onChange = (event) => {
        console.log("target", event);
    }

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={props.display}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            keepMounted
            onClose={props.closeModal}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            maxWidth = "md"
        >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">Connection Parameters</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <Grid container xs={12}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} style={{marginBottom:"1rem"}}>
                         {Object.keys(props.data).map((key, index) => ( 

                                  <TextField
                                    id="standard-full-width"
                                    name = "items"
                                    label={key}
                                    style={{ margin: 8 }}
                                    placeholder={props.data[key]}
                                    fullWidth
                                    margin="normal"
                                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                                    InputLabelProps={{
                                      shrink: true,
                                    }}
                                  />
                         ))}
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} color="primary">
                Submit
            </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the label you are talking about is the `key` in your `Object.keys` map loop.
Change you're `onChange` method to this:

```
const onChange = (event, key) => {
console.log("target", event.target.value);
console.log("label", key);
};
```

And your `onChange` prop of input to this:

```
<TextField
    ...otherProps
    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, key)}
 />
```

The `key` is the label and you'll have it beside value. You can checkout this sandbox for real usage: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dew-084bj?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

get values in onChange method (label,value) and in onChange of materialui pass prop as:

```
 {value=>onChangeHandle("<label Text>", value)}
```